# Convert Outlook.Mailitem to MIME type without saving or sending the mail

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook.Mailitem type object and I have to sent this object to a REST service so in order to do so either I have to convert Outlook.Mailitem to MIME type or Memory Stream type or in Bytes without disrupting the mail format since mail may contain attachments, images.
Is there a way we can convert Outlook.Mailitem to MIME type in C# without sending or saving the mail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Outlook comes with its own MIME converter - [IConverterSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iconvertersessioniunknown). You can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IConverterSession button | MAPIToMIMEStm). Since this is an Extended MAPI interface, it is only accessible from C++ or Delphi.

Another option is creating a MIME message one header and one MIME part at a time from the `MailItem` object properties.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language, I am also its author) is an option, it exposes [SafeMailItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm).`SaveAs` and [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`SaveAs` method; one of the supported formats is MIME (`olRfc822` = 1024).

Comment: By using redemption, do I need to save the mail.

Answer (score 0):

See [IConverterSession::MAPIToMIMEStm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb905203(v=office.12)) which converts a MAPI message to a MIME stream.

A sample code of using the `MAPIToMIMEStm` method can be found in [MFCMAPI](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/3372572/).

Comment: Here am stuck with creating an object of IStream type since MAPITOMIME Conversion is looking for IStream to return the value

Comment: Ayushi, take a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161130125259/http://hl7connect.blogspot.sk/2010/04/c-implementation-of-istream.html