# How to get MIME content of OFT

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi, mime-message

How to get MIME content of Outlook template file? I need to create an email from file and send it using Graph REST API. In [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) I found only different examples.

Comment: I suppose MS Graph doesn't know anything about Outlook template files. Where is your Outlook template file stored?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Outlook template file is stored on disc. A robotic process (RPA) should either read it and convert content to MIME or extract subject, body, etc, modify them and send email using Graph.

Answer (score 0):

OFT file is in the same format as MSG. Neither format contains any MIME data - it is simply not native to Outlook.

You would need to convert the file to the MIME format - see [Convert Outlook.Mailitem to MIME type without saving or sending the mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061101/convert-outlook-mailitem-to-mime-type-without-saving-or-sending-the-mail).

Comment: This API requires to start Outlook session, which I cannot use. I have to use following API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http with template file. I believe I need to either convert file to MIME or somehow extract parts like subject, body, etc

Comment: OFT is like an MSG file. It has no MIME content - open a file in Notepad. The file needs to be converted. You either do that explicitly in your code (PITA) or you use a library like Redemption (I am its author) - it does not require to start Outlook.